# IBM Business Process Management

Tags: web, ibm-bpm

What is used for IBM BPM in web development, I was told that it manages routes of business process, but could you explain it with real world examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IBM Business Process Manager is a single BPM platform that combines
>   human-centric and integration-centric capabilities into a Single
>   product

When the human-centric application is considered, often the Business Process requires to interact with users. To achieve this, the IBM BPM Platform provides user interfaces to be easily embedded within business process solutions.IBM Process Portal, used by business operations to access, execute, and manage tasks, can easily be configured and styled. A corporate look and feel can be defined using a graphical theme editor and applied consistently across all process applications.

For example, consider a Loan application process where the requirement is to handle Loan application for a particular bank. As part of this process Model,

- the loan process has to assign task to the Bank's clerk to initiate
  the loan application
- the manager to get the approval, integration task to credit the user account etc.

The BPM Platform makes it easier to handle human centric interactions using the embedded UI components which can be modelled very easily. This UI components can easily access the business Data and also having rich set of UI controls to work with.